# How to notify a running thread of a change

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I am working on a client/server project which watches a system event in the server and sends a notification change to clients. It consists of a Watcher object which does the watching, and the server object which creates threads for each client connecting to it. Considering the simplified code below (I included all of the necessary code)

Now, the problem is that the notification is received from the `mySrv` object and the `propertyChange` of `mySrv` is executed properly and `disMsg` is populated. However, I don't know how to reach the `run` method of the `ClientHandler` to execute the `notifyStatusChange()` to send out the change to clients. I tried joining threads and many different things but none worked. I would really appreciate if someone knows a better approach or point me to my mistakes and best practices perhaps) or show me specifically how to achieve that.

Thanks,

```
class MyServer implements PropertyChangeListener {

    // all the fields and imports are removed for the sake of brevity 

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket socket;
        InputStreamReader iReader;

        public ClientHandler(Socket ClientSocket) {
            try {
                socket = ClientSocket;
                iReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(iReader);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            String clientMessage;

            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (((clientMessage = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                        System.out.println("Client: " + clientMessage);
                    }

                    if (isChanged) {
                        System.out.println("Server1: " + dispMsg);
                        notifyStatusChange();
                        isChanged = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void goServer() {

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(1234);

            while (true) {
                s = ss.accept();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler((s)), "Thread for Client #" + counter);
                t.start();

                System.out.println("Connection " + counter + " received from: "
                        + s.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                counter++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyServer() {
        isChanged = false;
        if (dispMsg == null) {
            dispMsg = "Waiting for a change...";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {

        isChanged = true;
        dispMsg = "Event to String: " + pce.toString() + "\n"
                + "Property Name: " + pce.getPropertyName() + "\n"
                + "Old Value" + pce.getOldValue() + "\n";

    }

    public void notifyStatusChange() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.println(dispMsg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Watcher myWatcher = new WatcherDir();
            MyServer mySrv = new MyServer();

                myWatcher.addPropertyChangeListener(mySrv);
                myWatcher.start();
                mySrv.goServer();
                myWatcher.join();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Observer/Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/interview-when-do-we-use-observer-and-observable)?

Comment: Where is `isChanged` defined?  Did you make it `volatile`?  (I'm not saying that's the problem; I'm just trying to understand the code.)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, the use of `PropertyChangeListener` already implements the Observer/Observable desing pattern and also I have not problem receiving the notification by Watcher Object; however I cannot send the change to the `ClientHandler`'s `run` method.

Comment: @ajb: `isChange` is defined in the constructor and also is changed to `true` when a notification is received from the `Watcher` object. AS I mentioned previously, I received the notification but the `run` method of `ClientHandler` is not executed.

Comment: I also fixed some of typos there in the code as well. The constructor and the name of the main class did not match in the edited code above. Sorry!

Comment: @arashaga Maybe I should have asked, "where is `isChanged` declared?".  I don't see the declaration anywhere, and in particular I wanted to know, is it a member field of `MyServer` or declared somewhere else, and is it declared with the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @ajb: Sorry I just added that up there that I removed the fields and imports for the sake of brevity. I did not declare that as `volatile`. However `isChanged` is updated properly through `propertyChange` but the `run` method of `ClientHandler` is called only once during the creation of the thread within `goServer` but `Clienthandler`'s `run` method is never executed after that. Perhaps, somehow I should notify the client threads that are created dynamically as well but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few different issues here.

It seems the server waits for a connection from a client and creates and starts `ClientHandler` thread when it receives a connection. Once such a connection is received, its `run` method will execute, in its own thread.

So at this point we have two threads, the server thread and the client thread, but if the client doesn't write anything to the socket after connecting then the thread will block at `clientMessage = reader.readLine())`

Now let us assume that `propertyChange` is called in the main thread, and it sets `isChanged` to `true`. If I understand right you are expecting `notifyStatusChange` to be called. But there are some problems:

1. `ClientHandler.run` may be blocked reading from client connection when `isChanged` becomes `true`
2. Even if something is read from the socket, the thread may find that `isChanged` is false. This is because the change occurred in a different thread. If the variable is declared to be `volatile` then this will not occur.
3. The server accepts multiple connections, with a different thread for each connection. But each thread's run method can set `isChanged` to `false` so even if the value is propagated to all threads, only one of them will print the notification.

I know this is not complete answer but you need to fix these problems.

Comment: Excellent observation. I fixed the issued based on the steps you mentioned and it worked!thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is `producer-consumer`. Threads can share a `BlockingQueue`[1], where producer thread adds items and consumer thread takes it from the collection.

There are many examples of implementations.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your "propertyChange()" getting executed, if so , you code should work without any issue.
There is no need to execute "run()" again or join threads.

If you just want to notify a running Thread of a change, the following simple code will work.

```
package indika.java.core.network;



public class MyServer{
public boolean isChanged = false;
private String dispMsg;

public MyServer() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread mthread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
    mthread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    isChanged = true;
}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        boolean ok = true;
        while (ok) {
            System.out.println("Started thread!!!!");
            if (isChanged) {
                System.out.println("Server1: " + dispMsg);
                notifyStatusChange();
                isChanged = false;
                ok = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void notifyStatusChange() {
    System.out.println("notifyStatusChange -- ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new MyServer();
}}
```