# Call parent method in association relationship

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Sorry for my confusing title, but i don't know any better.
I have two classes: [image: My classes]

The first class (*called `MainClass`*) create a GUI that contain a Socket. When any data is received from Socket Class, `onReceived()` will be called. So in this `onReceived()` method, i want a way to send a message back to the `MainClass` so that `MainClass` can know position has change and call `setPostion()`.

So what is the properly way to do this (if necessary, correct my model for better practice). Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something the observer pattern could solve. Java has built-in support for that but you can also do it yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/interview-when-do-we-use-observer-and-observable

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Fildor: the comment is not the quality I want to see reflected in my answers and I do not have the time to write a more extensive one right now.

Comment: I've just read the Observer Pattern but i think it is overcomplicated in this case, do you have other way (changing the relationship) more simple.

Comment: I do not see anything simpler than the Observer Pattern if you do not want to poll for state changes, which is obviously the case. It does exactly what you described, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Snoob-  This is not even close to a good solution (yes I know that..But this is simple..). Why not just set a *global* boolean flag in `onReceived()` and in your `Main` class, keep checking/polling for that flag on some predefined interval (say 2 seconds) using a thread. If that flag has been set, `doWhatYouWant()` and reset the flag.

Comment: @TheLostMind Something like using [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) ? Well, for my taste, that's even more complicated, than a simple Observer, but hey ...

Comment: @Fildor - More or less, yes. :). Although even a single thread could do it (less efficiently..)

Comment: @TheLostMind that's a bad solution, obeserver pattern and listeners should be used in those cases.

Comment: @danizmax -I repeat.. *This is not even close to a good solution (yes I know that..But this is simple..)*

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Vannevel, i've used that pattern and it is really a good solution

Comment: btw, Can you explain the benefits of using Observer Pattern instead passing the GUI object to Socket and call GUI.setPostion() in onReiceved().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following;

Define listener interface:

```
public interface MyListener(){

    public void doNotify(String message);

}
```

The Socket class (has a methot to add listeners that are notified on onRecieve()):

```
public class SocketClass {

    private List<MyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyListener>();

    public void addListener(MyListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void onRecieve(){
        /* your code*/
        for (MyListener l : listeners)
            l.doNotify("Socket has recieved something ;P");
    }

}
```

The Gui class has a method that passes on the listener:

```
public class GuiClass() {

    SocketClass s = new SocketClass();

    public void addListener(MyListener listener) {
        s.addListener(listener);
    }

}
```

And finally the main class (implements the listener interface and adds itselef to GuiClass as listener):

```
public class MainClass implements MyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GuiClass g =  new GuiClass();
        g.addListener(this);

    }

    public void doNotify(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        setPostition();
    }

    private void setPosition()
        /* your code here */
    }

}
```

A good example is also [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java).

Good luck and Regards

Comment: Is it a kind of Observer Pattern ?

Comment: @Snoob yes, this is usually the best way to do it. The listeners are only trigered when they really need to be.

Comment: i think it is better to use java.util.Observer instead implement a new one.

Comment: @Snoob It's just an interface and in the end you will end doing the same thing. Sure you can use it if you want :P

Comment: Make sure you null-check the references before calling them :D