# Tracking database records consistently for change

Tags: java, database, communication

I have a very basic communication software that uses database to save messages entered by PC1 and PC2 uses the same database to read these messages and vice versa. My problem is, I need a technique so that I can keep checking the database for new messages. Or I need something that invokes a method to download the message when new record is inserted in the database. At the moment I use a timer which checks the DB every minute regardless of a new record being inserted. I'm looking for a more efficient way to perform the same task.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Well logically speaking, checking every minute is pretty inefficient. I would have the database fire off oa notification upon recieving a message

Comment: Exactly, I know it's inefficient. I thought about triggers or stored procedures too. But want to get some suggestions first.

Comment: this is also off-topic "too broad" and "opinion based"

Answer (score 0):

You can try Observer design pattern extending Java Observer. This design pattern when you get new message then notified.

I think this page very helpful for you.
[When should we use Observer and Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/interview-when-do-we-use-observer-and-observable)