# when., where and how we should use observer design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Tell me about observer pattern and its use case. I watched youtube video but didn't get. please someone explain it briefly.when , where and how we can use observer design pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should we use Observer and Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable)

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for event listeners. For example, when user presses certain button, objects listening to that event can be notified using observer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A classical example are GUIs. Usually, you design your GUI and register some elements like buttons in a listener/observer. You may do this in one class. If you click a button on your GUI, it will notify/fire an action to the listener/observer. In another class, which implements the observable interface you can define functions for the specific notifications.