# What is this line of code producing?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have been studying the observer pattern from **head_first_design_Patterns** book. The scenario is this " there is an ArrayList named as **observers** and it has all the observers that are implementing the **Observer** interface.
In the book,they are using a loop to update all the observers. The loop is:

```
 for(int i=0; observers.size();i++)
 {
     Observer observer= (Observer) observers.get(i);
     observer.update(temperature,humidity,pressure);
 }
```

I want to know how is the first statement of loop is working. Are we creating references to a particular observer here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should we use Observer and Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable)

Comment: Yes, you are getting a reference to the object that `observers.get(i)` returns. You are casting this object to an `(Observer)`, and then you can operate on it using the local variable `observer`.

Comment: @Ravi: I don't think the question has anything to do with the question you linked.

Comment: @uvesten I just pointed that question to first have a look in that question. As, that question has code mentioned related to this Design Pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how is the first statement of loop is working. Are
>   we creating references to a particular observer here?

This statement simply gets the element within the `ArrayList` at the specified `index` and makes sure that its an `Observer` type before pointing the reference to the retrieved object.

```
Observer observer= (Observer) observers.get(i);
```

If the cast is successful then the reference to the retrieved `object` gets used to update the data for that particular `object`.

```
observer.update(temperature,humidity,pressure);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are getting a reference to the object that `observers.get(i)` returns. You are casting this object to `(Observer)`, and then you can operate on it using the local variable `observer`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line just fetch the observer from the list. It creates a new reference to an existing object

Comment: What is **(Observer)**  for in the statement?

Comment: Type casting. Maybe during the list declaration the generic type is not there