# How can we make a value on one object reflect in a value in another object of a different type?

Tags: java

I have two classes `SubRecord` and `MainRecord`, which each have their individual fields. Neither of these is a subclass of the other. Multiple `SubRecord` objects correspond to one `MainRecord` object, as distinguished by field `id` in both. There is a field `val` in `SubRecord` that corresponds to value `val` in `MainRecord` which is of type `double`. How can I make it such that on updating `val` in `MainRecord`, all the corresponding objects of type `SubRecord` simultaneously update their fields `val` to the same value as well?

Comment: You could use Observable as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable

Comment: Make bidirectional relation insteed of unidirectional and use paren's record value

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `MainRecord` has a list of its subrecords. According to the common and obvious Java Bean pattern, the access to `val` should be provided via a setter. So you can just modify the internals of you `setVal` method like this:

```
public class MainRecord {
    private double val;
    private List<SubRecord> subs;
    // ...
    public void setVal(double newVal) {
        this.val = newVal;
        for(SubRecord entry : subs)
            entry.setVal(newVal);
    }
}
```

This is a very simple variation of an Observer pattern. See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do exactly that.  Here are your options:

1. Just don't.  Remove `val` from `SubRecord` and refactor every piece of code that tries to access `SubRecord.val` to find the `MainRecord` and access `MainRecord.val` instead.
2. Stop using immediate field access (`subRecord.val`) and use getters instead, (`subRecord.getVal()`) as the universal trend is in java. Then, get rid of `SubRecord.val` and rewrite your `SubRecord.getVal()` as follows: instead of `{ return val; }` make it find its `MainRecord` and do `return mainRecord.getVal()`.
3. Use the observer pattern.  Your `MainRecord` object would need to have a list of observers, to which your `SubRecord` objects are added, so whenever `MainRecord.val` changes, all the observers get notified, so they can update their own `val`.