# Uncaught TypeError: Invalid event target in RxJS subscribe block

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
const field = document.querySelector('.form-field');
const showHistoryButton = document.querySelector('#show-history');
const historyPanel = document.querySelector('#history');

const showHistory$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(showHistoryButton, 'click');

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(field, 'keyup')
    .debounceTime(200)
    .pluck('target', 'value')
    .filter(R.compose(R.not, R.isEmpty))
    .bufferWhen(() => showHistory$)
    .do(history => history.pop())
    .subscribe(history => {
        let contents = '';
        if(history.length > 0) {
            for(let item of history) {
                contents += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
            }
            historyPanel.innerHTML = contents;
        }
    });
```

The error I get is:

```
rxjs.5.5.2.js:3895 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid event target
    at Function.FromEventObservable.setupSubscription (rxjs.5.5.2.js:3895)
    at FromEventObservable._subscribe (rxjs.5.5.2.js:3917)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (rxjs.5.5.2.js:825)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable.subscribe (rxjs.5.5.2.js:813)
    at subscribeToResult (rxjs.5.5.2.js:2065)
    at BufferWhenSubscriber.openBuffer (rxjs.5.5.2.js:7489)
    at new BufferWhenSubscriber (rxjs.5.5.2.js:7442)
    at BufferWhenOperator.call (rxjs.5.5.2.js:7427)
    at Observable.subscribe (rxjs.5.5.2.js:810)
    at DoOperator.call (rxjs.5.5.2.js:9862)
```

And when I uncommented pieces of code, it looks like the culprit is `subscribe` method even when it's empty. I am using RxJS 5.5.2 and the only dependency is Ramda.

Comment: I guess `field` or `showHistoryButton` is not found /`null`.

Comment: subscribe is not the culprit. Subscribe does just init the emission ([info about subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767880/what-does-subscribe-do-and-how-it-is-related-to-observable/46769019#46769019))

Comment: You are right, the error is in line `.bufferWhen(() => showHistory$)` and that's because I applied `class="show-history"` instead of `id`. The error wasn't in subscribe - it was only appearing because RxJS streams are only run when there is at least one subscriber.