# In RxJS, why does a pipe get executed once for each subscription?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to have multiple subscriptions to react to an observable event, but I want to log the event as well, so I pipe it through a `do()` operator in which I do the logging.

The problem is, the event gets logged once for each of the subscriptions I create!

I'm getting around this at the moment by creating a `Subject` and calling `next` on it from an event callback, which allows me to log the event once and trigger multiple subscriptions as well.

Here is some code that demonstrates the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xerurd

I have a feeling I'm missing something, isn't there a more "RxJS" way of doing this?

EDIT:

I'm not asking for a difference between hot & cold observable, in fact I was using a hot observable - the one created by `fromEvent()` and was wondering why does my presumably hot event source behave like it's cold.

I realize now - after reading about `share()` - that `pipe()` "turns" your observable cold i.e. returns a cold one based on the your source (which may be cold, may be hot)

Comment: This is what RxJS is supposed to do. You can use `share()` operator if you want to keep only one subscription to its source.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! `share()` indeed seems to be what I'm looking for, but could you perhaps (if you know why it is so) explain the reasoning behind such a design? It seems to me that maybe "sharing" should be a default and, "not sharing" should have an operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does subscribe do, and how it is related to Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767880/what-does-subscribe-do-and-how-it-is-related-to-observable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Observable sequences are cold by default, each subscription will have a separate set of site effects.

If you want your side effect to be executed only once - you can share subscription by broadcasting a single subscription to multiple subscribers. To do this you can use `share`, `shareReplay`, etc.

To better understand how it works, what is "cold" and publish, refer to the RxJS v4 documentation:

[**4.8 Use the publish operator to share side-effects**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines#48-use-the-publish-operator-to-share-side-effects)

Comment: if `share()` and multicasting stuffs did not solve your issue. Look at my answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : `share()` is finally working. Please have a look to the comments below. Thx to @Oles Savluk.

I let my answer below for the records. It may help.

---

`share()` and multicasting stuffs did not solve my very similar issue.

Here is how I solved it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dhzisp

```js
const finalSource = new Subject();
fromEvent(button3, "click").pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log("this happens only once")
  }) 
).subscribe(() => finalSource.next())

finalSource.subscribe(
  () => console.log("first final subscription")
)

finalSource.subscribe(
  () => console.log("second final subscription")
)

finalSource.subscribe(
  () => console.log("third final subscription")
)
```

Comment: You basically did multicasting "manually". Same will happen if you put `share()` right after `tap()` in `badSource` - side effect will be executed once.

Comment: This is totally fine, but longer and you are not propagating errors which might cause issues

Comment: Ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ... I think I just figured something out : during my tests, I put the `share()` **BEFORE** the `tap()`, and indeed it did not work! Now, it makes sense to me: it can only "share" what is "before itself". I need to "share" **AFTER** all the pipes.
Anyway, thank you so much for this small explanation (and you are totally right about the no-propagation of errors ... I missed this part)
... feeling dumb right now! :(