# Why do we need LiveData and ViewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have used `LiveData and ViewModel` example 
but i dont understand use of this feature because i can change value directly without use this feature even this is growing number of line in code by using observing code and same as in `ViewModel` by creating `MutableLiveData`.

below `ViewModel` Code
    public class FirstViewModel extends ViewModel {

```
    // Create a LiveData with a String
    public MutableLiveData<String> mCurrentName;


    public MutableLiveData<String> getCurrentName() {
        if (mCurrentName == null) {
            mCurrentName = new MutableLiveData<String>();
        }
        return mCurrentName;
    }


}
```

Using in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirstViewModel mModel;
ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBinding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);


        // Get the ViewModel.
        mModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FirstViewModel.class);


        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
                // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
                mBinding.mNameTextView.setText(newName);
            }
        };

        // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
        mModel.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);


       mBinding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              String anotherName = mBinding.etField.getText().toString();
             mModel.getCurrentName().setValue(anotherName);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewModel` and `LiveData` android architecture components together help to create *lifecycle aware* applications.

**ViewModel:**
ViewModel classes are often used to significantly segregate the view logic (present in Activity classes) from the business logic which is contained in the ViewModel classes. This segregation is a good architecture design and becomes very important while maintaining large projects.

**LiveData:**
LiveData helps in implementing the [Observer Observable pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable) in a lifecycle aware manner.

In your case, it may seem trivial since you are only setting value for a `TextView`. However consider common scenarios like hitting an api to retrieve data, etc. In such cases, the `ViewModel` is responsible for providing the data to be displayed in the `Activity`, which when done with the help of `LiveData` can help avoid crashes by ensuring lifecycle awareness easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about live data from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). It is like `Observer` that looks for changing of data and notify **observers** that **observable** object has changed

Answer (score 0):

In simple words its make your life eazy as a programmer when we go into the details like activity/fragment lifecycle handling, displaying updated data and more importantly separating the presentation layer from business logic and to create a more well structured application. please find more details from [here](https://medium.com/sears-israel/when-and-why-to-use-android-livedata-93d7dd949138)