# Observer Pattern Where Multiple Subjects call one Observer

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I'm attempting to make a simple Mario game in `java`. With this, I wanted a `listener` for when a `Goomba`(The main enemy in Mario) is killed. After a bit of research, I looked into the `Observer Pattern`

I made this `interface`

```
public interface GoombaDeathListener {
    void onGoombaDeath(Goomba goomba);
}
```

Next I made myself a `class` for my `Player`

```
public class Player extends Entity implements GoombaDeathListener {
    @Override
    public void onGoombaDeath(Goomba goomba) {. . .}
}
```

I also made a `Goomba` `class`

```
public class Goomba extends Entity {
    ArrayList<GoombaDeathListener> deathListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onDeath() {
        for (GoombaDeathListener listener : deathListeners) {
            listener.onGoombaDeath(this);  
        }
    }
}
```

I believe(not sure if I'm in full understanding of this) that this makes `Goomba` the `observer`, and I want more than one `Goomba` which means that I'd have multiple `ArrayLists` of `GoombaDeathListeners`

So I have 2 Questions: What am I not understanding of the `Observer Pattern`, and how can I have multiple `Subjects`(`Goomba`) call `onGoombaDeath(this)` when they die

Comment: Your current `Goomba` class is already on the right track, and when the Goomba dies it should notify all listeners.  I don't see any code which creates listeners, and passes to them a `Goomba` reference.

Comment: `this makes Goomba the observer` - no, `Goomba` is the observable.  `GoombdaDeathListener` is the observer.  An observer is one who observes an observable.  An observable is something which can be observed by another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I not understanding of the Observer Pattern

Your `GoobmaDeathListener` is the Observer. It is observing events on the observable, your `Goomba`.

You might want to look at a more detailed explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744816/340088

> how can I have multiple Subjects(Goomba) call onGoombaDeath(this) when they die

Well each `Goomba` (Observable) must have a reference to the list of Observers. Most probably you would want to introduce a class in the middle, called something like `GoombaObservers` which manages the list of interested `Observers`. It would offer a method like `notifyGoombaDeath()` which internally does the loop to call `onGoombaDeath()`.

You might also want to see what Java already offers out of the box with [`java.util.Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html).

Comment: Would it best to then make this "middle class" static then? I can't make an instance of it in the Goomba class because it would create the original issue. (I ask as I hate static)

Comment: Well ideally not static. Would it be a problem to pass it as a constructor argument to each `Goomba`? (If you are using some framework like Spring it would automatically inject it for you too through the constructor.)You would then be able to add or remove Observers to the `GoombaObservers` class dynamically, and all `Goomba` instances would be automatically notifying everyone. If you really can't pass it, you can also use the Singleton pattern to initialise the `GoombaObservers` instance once and only once throughout your program (the static method would just get the same singleton instance).